# Error : 'QtGui/QMainWindow': No such file or directory : Qt 5.1.1

Tags: windows, qt5.1

I have installed the `Qt5.1.1` and create a new Gui Application. The code in mainwindow.h shows:

```
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#else
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#endif
```

I think it is fine. But when I run it, I have this:

```
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/QMainWindow': No such file or directory
```

I know when I replace

```
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#else
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#endif
```

to

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
```

it works.

I just wonder why the default code is wrong and how to make the defauly code right.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may have another option.

You can also add `widgets` in your `.pro` file like

**`greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets`**

By adding this line in `.pro` file, Now you just no need to worry about Qt version and include file like `<QtGui/QMainWindow>` or `<QtWidgets/QMainWindow>`

Hope it will useful to you.

Comment: Can you post your `.pro` file code with error/problem, so I can help you.

Comment: For Qt 5.10 on MacOS only `<QtWidgets/QMainWindow>` worked for me. `QtGui` seems has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but it is with nuances. If that code is in the *.h* file:

```
    #if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
    #include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
    #else
    #include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
    #endif
```

the error appears. It seems like QT_VERSION does not defined correctly. But if I move this code to the *.cpp* file, it is all right. 
The problem was solved as follows:

1. Add to the *.pro* file this:

```
    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
        QT += widgets
        DEFINES += HAVE_QT5
    }
```

2. Add to the *.h* file this:

```
    #ifdef HAVE_QT5
    #include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
    #else
    #include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
    #endif
```